# Shade a dependency in maven which is used by other dependency as well

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin, relocation, shading

I am stuck with one shading stuff, Need help if there is known way out.
I have a project module which has bunch of dependencies and I want to shade and relocate one of the dependency. I did that, but the problem is the other dependency also uses the dependency that I shaded, but that doesn’t use the relocated class, is there any way to make the other dependency use the relocated shaded class instead of the original.
The catch is I can’t shade this other dependency due to other conflicts.

Module
DependencyA (uses dependency B as well)
DependencyB (shaded and relocated)

Want to make dependency A use relocated classes in the Module rather than direct dependency B

Any help, even if it is something which can not be done, Please let me know!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reference to a shaded jar in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31798353/how-to-reference-to-a-shaded-jar-in-maven)